# GCC __attribute__((always_inline)) and lambdas, is this syntax correct?

Tags: gcc, c++11, lambda, inline

I am using GCC 4.6 as part of the lpcxpresso ide for a Cortex embedded processor. I have very limited code size, especially when compiling in debug mode. Using **attribute**((always_inline)) has so far proven to be a good tool to inline trivial functions and this saves a lot of code bloat in debug mode while still maintaining readability. I expect it to be somewhat mainstream and supported in the future because it is mentioned here http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/CIAJGAIH.html

Now to my question: Is this the correct Syntax for declaring a Lambda always inline?

```
#define ALWAYS_INLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
[](volatile int &i)ALWAYS_INLINE{i++;}
```

It does work, my question is will it continue to work in future and what can I do to ensure it works in the future. If I ever switch to another major compiler that supports c++11 will I find a similar keyword which I can replace the **attribute**((always_inline)) with?
If I were to meet my fairy godmother I would wish for a compiler directive which causes all lambdas which are constructed as temporaries with empty constructors and bound by reference to be automatically inlined even in debug mode. Any ideas?

Comment: The C++11 syntax would be `[[always_inline]]`. But GCC doesn't seem to use the compliant syntax yet. It may be of limited value to discuss where a pre-C++11 GCC attribute goes on a C++11 lambda.

Comment: so what your saying is that there will be a compliant syntax which will be portable in future. That would mean porting my code to c++ compiler X in future would only require me to change the contents of my #define?

Comment: @MSalters there's no such attribute in the standard C++. GCC-specific attribute in standard C++11 syntax for such functionality is `[[gnu::always_inline]]`.

Comment: @Ruslan: That's why I say that the syntax **would be** `[[always-inline]]`. It's explicitly hypothetical. IIRC, GCC 4.6 did not have the `[[gnu::always-inline]]` syntax either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it continue to work in future?

Likely but, `always_inline` is compiler specific and since there is no standard specifying its exact behavior with lambda, there is no guaranty that this will continue to work in the future.

> What can I do to ensure it works?

This depends on the compiler not you. If a future version drops support for `always_inline` with lambda, you have to stick with a version that works or code your own preprocessor that inlines lambdas with an `always_inline`-like keyword.

> If I ever switch to another major compiler that supports c++11 will I
>   find a similar keyword?

Likely but again, there is no guaranty. The only real standard is the C++ `inline` keyword and it is not applicable to lambdas. For non-lambda it only suggests inlining and tells the compiler that a function may be defined in different compile units.